# Include files in verilog: compilation options for modelsim

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I have to compile a file (x.sv). In x.sv, there are a bunch of "`include y.v". The content of y.v is just a set of assign statements. Ex: assign a = b&&c. Signals a,b and c are defined in x.sv.

I tried compiling as follows:  `vlog -sv -work work x.sv +incdir+ "path to y.v"`

These files have been handed over to me and I have to simulate it.

The reason its done this way is because there are a lot of assign statements in y.v and will make x.sv more readable.

### file x.sv

```
module x (input b, input c, output d);
  wire a; 
  reg d;
  `include y.v
  always @* d <= a;
endmodule
```

---

### file: y.v

```
assign a = b && c;
```

Modelsim is able to find the files, but it says "near "assign": syntax error, unexpected assign, expecting class." in the file y.v

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is not because of the `` `include `` but with the lines before it. Unfortunately, many syntax errors point to the next line after the error because the mistaken syntax has it lost, and the `assign` statement in the included file just happens to be *the next line*.

Your problem is you are mixing two different styles of port declaration syntax; ANSI and non-ANSI style. The `reg d;` is not expected. Put it into the port header. Other issues after you fix that:

- Use `always_comb` and never `always @*` in SystemVerilog. @* misses
  events at time 0 as well as constants.
- Do not use NBAs `<=` in
  combinatorial logic.

Answer (score -1):

That should be `+incdir+<dir>` for each directory you want the simulator to look in for `include'd files.  `.` for the current directory usually works or specify it explicitly.

Comment: Modelsim is able to find the files, but it says "near "assign": syntax error, unexpected assign, expecting class."

Comment: Ok.  You'll have to give us more to work with then.   Please include the actual code that is pointed to by the error and preferably a minimal example showing the problem if you can.  People are helpful here but not clairvoyant.

Comment: I have added more details.